# How to buid keras model with multi dimensional input multi dimensional output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I want to use sensor reading to estimate some quantities. My sensor readings in each time step have 9 elements and the out quantities have 4 elements

```
input_size = (304414,9)
target_size = (304414,4)
```

I want to create a RNN model to estimate the output.

For preprocessing and create data set, I used this function

```
def create_dataset(dataset, look_back):
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(len(dataset)-look_back):
        dataX.append(dataset[i:(i+look_back)]) # all 22 columns for X
        dataY.append(dataset[i + look_back, 9:14]) # first 8 columns for Y, just as an example
    return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY)


data = np.concatenate((input, output), axis=1)
X, Y = create_dataset(data, 1)
```

Now, my data set has been changed to
input_size = (304413,1,13)
target_size = (304413,4)

The model which I used is

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(1, 13, input_length=304413))
model.add(LSTM(12, input_shape=(304413,1,13), kernel_initializer='normal',activation='relu',return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(12, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu'))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),metrics=['accuracy','mse'])
```

But after trying to use `model.fit` I encountered with this error

```
ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1021, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1010, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1000, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 859, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 264, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(f'Input {input_index} of layer "{layer_name}" is '

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_20" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 304413), found shape=(None, 1, 13)
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: I don't understand why you need an LSTM for a single time-step problem here? Are you sure that's what you need?

Comment: @thushv89 What to you mean by sing time-step? It has 304414 time steps. The input shape is '(304414,9)'. Did I have done something wrong?

Comment: So you have just one datapoint with 300K steps? In anycase, `input_shape` to your model should be in format `(time steps, feature dim)` (`batch_dim` is automatically added). FYI, i don't know how performant an LSTM that's trained on a single record would be, so you might have to think of ways to break down to multple records

Answer (score 1):

About the shape I think you simply have to set the `input_shape` inside the **first** layer of your sequential model.

Also @thushv89's comment made me notice a mistake in the `target_size` which cannot be `(304414,4)`, since you used `return_sequences=True`.
This is because with this setting the model will output all the hidden states of each time steps and you'll have a 3D output where:

- The first dimension indicates the number of samples in the batch.
- The second dimension indicates the number of time steps in the input sequence.
- The third dimension indicates the dimensionality of the output space.

So in your case the output must be `(None, 1, 4)`. See this tutorial for [Working with RNNs](https://keras.io/guides/working_with_rnns/), if you haven't already.

The code:

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(1, 13, input_length=304413, input_shape=(1, 13)))
model.add(LSTM(12, kernel_initializer='normal',activation='relu',return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(12, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu'))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),metrics=['accuracy','mse'])
```

Comment: `input_shape` needs to be `(1,13)` (batch dim should not be included). Also, output of this model will be a `(None, 1, 4)` because `return_sequences=True` (if I'm not mistaken), in which case the labels need to have an extra dim.